# User prompt to Continue or Clear a time duration calculator

Tags: python, time, calculator, duration

I am very inexperienced with any programming language. I decided for my first for-fun/leaning project to be creating a calculator to add different durations of time (ex. add the length of several songs to find how long an album is).

So far the user input method is pretty basic, and I'll work to fix that once the basics work, so bear with me on that. The calculator is currently capable of adding two times together and printing the correct answer.

My main problem is creating a functional Continue/Clear user prompt. I have a loop asking if the user wants to continue, clear, or exit. User input works correctly, but I don't know how to actually "continue or clear".

My idea: Upon hitting continue, the previous total will become firstNumber, and the user will only be prompted for the second number (nextNumber) and will be given a new sum and receive the same continue/clear/exit prompt. If the user hits clear, it will start at the very beginning and the user will be prompted for a new firstNumber.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Below is the code:

```
import datetime

# holds first entry
print("Enter the first number")
seconds_1 = int(input("Seconds: "))
minutes_1 = int(input("Minutes: "))
hours_1 = int(input("Hours: "))

# holds second entry
print("Enter another number")
seconds_2 = int(input("Seconds: "))
minutes_2 = int(input("Minutes: "))
hours_2 = int(input("Hours: "))

# calculation
duration_1 = datetime.timedelta(hours=hours_1, minutes=minutes_1, seconds=seconds_1)
duration_2 = datetime.timedelta(hours=hours_2, minutes=minutes_2, seconds=seconds_2)
total = duration_1 + duration_2
print(total)

# continue, clear, or exit
contClear = input("Continue: Y | Clear: N | Exit: X: ")
cont = False
while cont == False:
    if contClear.upper() == "Y" or contClear.upper() == "YES":
        print("Next")
        cont = True
    elif contClear.upper() == "N" or contClear.upper() == "NO":
        print("Cleared")
        cont = True
    elif contClear.upper() =="X" or contClear.upper() == "EXIT":
        print("Exiting")
        cont = True
    else:
        print("Invalid Entry")
        contClear = input("Continue: Y | Clear: N | Exit: X: ")
print("DONE")
```

Comment: Why are you putting your code in classes like that? Python isn't Java. Unless you are planning on creating and using objects of a given class, there is no reason to put your code in class definitions.

Comment: The plan was to make firstNumber become the previous total, so continue has firstNumber = total

Comment: In addition, the only reason you find yourself using `break` in your `while` loop, in this case, is because you use `if` rather than `elif`. If you had `if`, `elif`... `else` then only one condition could be `True` in each loop, so the other conditions wouldn't be checked and your loop would break naturally. Your learning seems to have jumped a few too many steps ahead and you're going off-course to correct the issues that's creating.

Comment: Rather than things like `firstNumber` and `secondNumber` just have things like `total` and `number`. Get a new number in each pass through the loop and add it to total which is initialized prior to the loop. Also, I recommend letting the user just enter time like `1:30:05` or `4:15` rather than 3 separate prompts (which might be annoying, especially if embedded in a larger loop).

Comment: @John Coleman `enter time like 1:30:05 or 4:15` yeah I'm not sure how to do that yet, but I plan on doing that

Comment: I'm struggling to gauge this question. I'll be home soon and was going to answer (if it's not already). I also self taught from Stack Overflow, so I empathise. I can't tell whether the changes to the question based on feedback are because you know, and understand, the issues or whether you're Googling the feedback and making snap changes. In any case, your question content shouldn't be radically transforming like this here.

Comment: In other words, if you're rapidly responding to feedback on your initial code by researching the issues highlighted in comments here then we're going off-track from the premise of the question and forcing you in to new programming that you might not properly understand. That's a lose/lose.